# Is there a better way to format this date string

Tags: c#, string, datetime, date, format

is there are better way to structure this line of code, as you can see, I am changing the format of a string that contains a date.

```
lblCourseStartDate.Text = String.Format("{0:D}", DateTime.Parse(CourseStartDate));
```

I just found it untidy that I am converting twice or three times to get the format I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `DateTime.Parse(CourseStartDate)).ToLongDateString()` or `DateTime.Parse(CourseStartDate)).ToString("D")`, which might be a little cleaner. But, you're basically stuck doing the Parse and then the Format regardless of what you do.